# Setting AWS SDK credentials in RN Expo application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo

I am using AWS in my current project (Serverless application) and using AWS SDK for S3 and SES (Simple Email Service) managing.
Recently, I've faced with the security issue. I don't know where to store Access Key ID and Secret Key from AWS. In the web application, I am using environmental variables for these purposes and don't commit them into github. But how to deal with it within the expo? I don't want to place creds in code. Could you guys advise me some options? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you running your code?

Comment: in the  WebStorm

Comment: I meant on what AWS service?